# Equivalent Definitions of Twisted Sheaf $ \mathcal {O}(1)$

Tags: algebraic-geometry, sheaf-theory

Let $\mathcal {O}(-1)$ be the tautological line bundle $X$ of $ \Bbb CP^1$, where $X=\{(z,l) \in \Bbb C^2 \times \Bbb CP^1 : z \in l \}$ together with canonical projection $X \to \Bbb CP^1$ (line bundle property and co easy to prove).

Futhermore we define $ \mathcal {O}(1):= \mathcal {O}(-1)^{\vee}$,  where $ \mathcal {O}(-1)^{\vee}$  can be defined in two equivalent ways :

$ \mathcal {O}(-1) \otimes \mathcal {O}(-1)^{\vee}= \mathcal {O}_{\Bbb CP^1}$ is the same as to define it as $ \mathcal {O}(-1)^V :=  \underline{Hom}_{\mathcal{O}_{\Bbb CP^1}}(\mathcal{O}(-1),\mathcal{O}_{\Bbb CP^1})$  (follows from evaluation map).

The other way to define $ \mathcal {O}(1)$ is the following (compare with eg Liu’s AG, page 165 or see image below):

Obviously we have $ \Bbb CP^1 = Proj (B)$ where $B = \oplus _n  B_n:=\mathbb{C}[X,Y] $ is graded $\mathbb{C}$-algebra in canonical way (polynomial grade). We set $B(n)$ as a new graduated $\mathbb{C}$-algebra by defining recursively $B(n)_m := B_{n+m}$.
Liu defined the $ \mathcal {O}_{\Bbb CP^1 }$ -module $ \mathcal {O}(n)$ by setting $ \mathcal {O}(n) := \widetilde{B(n)}$ .

My question is: Why this both definitions of $ \mathcal {O}(1)$ are equivalent?

Here Liu's definition of "twisting":

[image]

Comment: Hint: Take the standard open cover of the projective line (consisting of two copies of the affine line) and compute the transition functions for these line bundles with respect to this cover.

Comment: [Related post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2273224/two-definitions-of-mathcalo-mathbbpnl)

Answer (score 1):

Let $U\subset\mathbb{CP}^1$ be an open subset.

Sections $U\to p^{-1}(U)$ of $p\colon X\to\mathbb{CP}^1$ look like $[x:y]\mapsto(f_1/g_1,f_2/g_2)$ where $f_1$ and $g_1$ are homogeneous polynomials of the same degree, and the same holds for $f_2$ and $g_2$. We moreover require $f_1/g_1\cdot x+f_2/g_2\cdot y=0$, and such that $g_1$ and $g_2$ have no zeroes on $U$. This corresponds to the rational function $f_1/g_1\cdot y^{-1}=-f_2/g_2\cdot x^{-1}$ of homogeneous degree $-1$, so gives a well-defined section of $\mathcal O_{\mathbb{CP}^1}(-1)$. Indeed, at $[x:y]\in U$ with $y\ne0$ the expression $f_1/g_1\cdot y^{-1}$ is well-defined and when $x\ne0$ the expression $f_2/g_2\cdot x^{-1}$ is well-defined.

Conversely, suppose $F/G$ is a section of $\mathcal O_{\mathbb{CP}^1}(-1)$, i.e., where $F$ and $G$ are homogeneous and $\deg(G)=\deg(F)+1$ and $G$ has no zeroes on $U$. Then $[x:y]\mapsto (Fy/G,-Fx/G)$ is a section $U\to p^{-1}(U)$.

Comment: probably you want the condition  $f_1/g_1\cdot y-f_2/g_2\cdot x=0$? Let me try to understand your argument: the local section  $U\to p^{-1}(U)= X \vert _U=\{(z,l) \in \Bbb C^2 \times U: z \in l \}$ is given in full terms as  $[x:y]\mapsto (((f_1/g_1)(x,y),(f_2/g_2)(x,y)), [x:y])$. we abbreviate $ (f_i/g_i)(x,y) $ to simply  $f_i/g_i$ keeping in mind that we consider it as evaluated in $[x:y]$. In order to land in $ X$ the ratios of $(f_1/g_1,f_2/g_2)$ and $c \cdot (x,y) $ should coinside for every non zero constant $ c$. So we conclude $f_1/g_1\cdot (f_2/g_2)^{-1}= x \cdot y^{-1}$ and this is

Comment: equivalent to the condition  $f_1/g_1\cdot y-f_2/g_2\cdot x=0$, isn't it?

Comment: Moreover it is known that in contrast to $\mathcal O_{\mathbb{CP}^1}(1)$ the tautological bundle $X =\mathcal O_{\mathbb{CP}^1}(-1)$ as it was defined above has no global sections.

Comment: Right, requiring the condition $f_1/g_1\cdot y-f_2/g_2\cdot x=0$ is also ok; it is a matter of convention. I chose the (possibly non-standard) convention that $[a:b]\in\mathbb P^1$ corresponds to the line $ax+by=0$.

Comment: And yes, I agree that $\mathcal O_{\mathbb{CP}^1}(-1)$ has no global sections.

Comment: But the way you approach it is exactly that one I was interested in as I posed this question providing exactly as you did a bridge between topological and abgebraic descriptions of the tautological bundle. I think here the problm with $\mathcal {O}(-1)$  and wrong conclusion is that it has non trivial global sections came from some swapped denominator, since the right conclusion should be that no local sections of $\mathcal {O}(-1)$ should be able to glue to global ones. In contrast I think that if we apply exactly the same methods of your analysis to $\mathcal {O}(1)$ this should give correct

Comment: result. I try to borrow some time next days to think carefully about it

Comment: I think that topologically we can describe  $\mathcal {O}(-1)$ in analogy to $X$ as $X^{\vee}:=\{(z,[v]) \ \vert \ : [v] \in  \Bbb CP^1, z \in  ( \mathbb{C} \cdot v)^{\vee} \}$ and do similar analysis as you did above. If we fix an open set $U\subset\mathbb{CP}^1$, do you see how in this case the local sections over $ U $ should look like? Say for $ U := \mathbb{CP}^1 - V(L) $ for certain linear polynomial $ L$. Do they allow similar description as you did for $ X $ in terms of fractions of polynomials?